# How to verify password in the below code snippet

Tags: php

I have two questions here :

1. Is it fine using the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` for generating random string or is it only better to take strings directly from `/dev/random`?
2. I've written the below code to generate a unique salt and a salted hash for each users password now how do i verify the password? I am confused on how to authorize because the hashes are random due to salts presence.

Comment: If this is for logging in, just use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I,ve used it already i just want to know how **password_hash()** is working

Comment: If you want to know how it works - simply check its source https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/password.c#L261

Comment: The normal method is to store the salt as a prefix to the result hash string. The salt is a known length so it is easy to extract later. i.e.  calculate hash from salt + password. Concatenate the salt and resultHash together. Return it. That is what gets stored. when verifying you get the password and the existing resultHash. Just extract the salt from the existing resultHash and you can do the hash calculation  to verify the password is correct.

Comment: @RyanVincent can i see the code .

Comment: exanple code: https://eval.in/618822. This is what the PHP passwordHash and verify functions do. They also base64_encode it. I use the same method with encrypted strings so I don't have to bother about storing the salt separately.

Comment: @RyanVincent Simply hashing with a salt is insufficient. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [Modern, Secure, Salted Password Hashing Made Simple](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes)

Comment: @Zaph, yes, we have talked this before and I agree with you this time as well as last time :)   It really was just a demonstration of how to store the salt and the hash together and split them up again. Nothing more than that. For may own routines then I use all the secure stuff. I have classes for it but they are OTT just to demonstrate the technique.   I am 'quite paranoid' about it.

Comment: Even *hash from salt + password* is a poor solution, it is better to use HMAC(salt, password). Consider that it is the users who are at risk from poor password handling, they expect and deserve good security.

Answer (score 1):

For 1: See here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101117

It answers perfectly what you're looking for.

For 2: For checking the password. First, you need the salt to check it, so you need to store the salt somewhere. Make 3 functions out of it:

```
function getSalt($length = 33) {
    return openssl_digest(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length), 'sha512')
        . openssl_digest('intercept9', 'sha512');
}

function encrypt($salt, $password) {    
    $password = md5($pass . $salt);
    return $password;
}

function verify($salt, $password, $hash) {
   return encrypt($salt, $password) == $hash;
}

$salt = getSalt();
$hash = encrypt($salt, 'root');
var_dump(verify($salt, 'root', $hash));
```

But try to rely on the password_* functions php already has implemented.

Comment: Simply hashing with a salt is insufficient. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph yes i agree with you **key stretching** is the thing you are telling about. but doing so for every person imagine for a site having 10000 users and the server bandwidth is less. Would that effect making the login function go havoc ?

Comment: It is not key stretching, it is iteration that is important although key derivation functions such as PBKDF2 can be used. If 100ms is not acceptable then a shorter duration is still much better than <1us per hash. At 1us * 10K users * 10K most common passwords = 100s, that is not acceptable and we can easily provide better protection. Assume an attacker  has hashing hardware 10 to 1000 times faster.